How to install octane in Laravel 10/filament app on home server?
I try to install octane in my Laravel 10/filament app and I run it with command :
$ php artisan  octane:start --server=swoole --host=local-quizzes.com   --port=8002  --watch

INFO  Server running….


Local: http://local-quizzes.com:8002

Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
where local-quizzes.com is my virtual host of Apache2/Kubuntu 22.04 on home laptop. Project is in dev stage and has no many data.

I have installed swoole :
 dpkg -s      php8.2-openswoole
Package: php8.2-openswoole
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: php
Installed-Size: 2388
Maintainer: Open Swoole Group <hello@openswoole.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 22.0.0-1~ubuntu22.04.0
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libpq-dev, php8.2-cli, php8.2-curl, php8.2-mysqlnd
Pre-Depends: php-common (>= 2:69~)
Conffiles:
 /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/openswoole.ini d96aae22813d5e025618d02d57881924
Description: Programmatic Server for PHP with Async IO, Coroutines and Fibers
Homepage: https://openswoole.com
root@master-at-home:~# dpkg -s      php8.2-openswoole
Package: php8.2-openswoole
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: php
Installed-Size: 2388
Maintainer: Open Swoole Group <hello@openswoole.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 22.0.0-1~ubuntu22.04.0
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libpq-dev, php8.2-cli, php8.2-curl, php8.2-mysqlnd
Pre-Depends: php-common (>= 2:69~)
Conffiles:
 /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/openswoole.ini d96aae22813d5e025618d02d57881924
Description: Programmatic Server for PHP with Async IO, Coroutines and Fibers
Homepage: https://openswoole.com
root@master-at-home:~# php -v
PHP 8.2.21 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2024 16:26:28) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.21, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

My project :
php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 10.48.17

with :
"laravel/octane": "^2.5",
"filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",

I try to use octane in this app as filamentphp is quite hard library and it works rather slowly under dev, especially it on pages it has 50-100 rows and more.
When I run site under http://local-quizzes.com url - it works, but I do not see any difference in performance.
I suppose that I need to run it under url :
http://local-quizzes.com:8002

as port 8002 was passed in command line.
Is it so ?
But I got error in this case :
Target class [config] does not exist.

I found in log file :
[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"config\" does not exist at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:912)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(912): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(795): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(961): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(731): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(946): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1454): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1366): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php(104): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->getLocale()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php(63): Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider->getLocale()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php(56): Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider->updateLocale()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(458): Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider->Carbon\Laravel\{closure}()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(286): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(266): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->invokeListeners()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1401): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportLocales/SupportLocales.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->setLocale()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentHook.php(23): Livewire\Features\SupportLocales\SupportLocales->hydrate()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/ComponentHookRegistry.php(54): Livewire\ComponentHook->callHydrate()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/EventBus.php(60): Livewire\ComponentHookRegistry::Livewire\{closure}()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/helpers.php(98): Livewire\EventBus->trigger()
#19 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Mechanisms/HandleComponents/HandleComponents.php(96): Livewire\trigger()
#20 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireManager.php(97): Livewire\Mechanisms\HandleComponents\HandleComponents->update()
#21 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Mechanisms/HandleRequests/HandleRequests.php(94): Livewire\LivewireManager->update()
#22 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(46): Livewire\Mechanisms\HandleRequests\HandleRequests->handleUpdate()
#23 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(259): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#24 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#25 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(806): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#26 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#27 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#28 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#29 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#30 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#31 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#32 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#33 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#34 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#35 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle()
#36 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#37 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#38 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#39 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle()
#40 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#41 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(805): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#42 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(784): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#43 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(748): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
#44 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(737): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#45 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
#46 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#47 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportDisablingBackButtonCache/DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#48 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Livewire\Features\SupportDisablingBackButtonCache\DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware->handle()
#49 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#50 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#51 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(36): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#52 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle()
#53 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#54 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#55 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#56 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#57 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#58 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle()
#59 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#60 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle()
#61 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#62 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#63 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#64 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/octane/src/ApplicationGateway.php(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
#65 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/octane/src/Worker.php(84): Laravel\Octane\ApplicationGateway->handle()
#66 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/swoole-server(120): Laravel\Octane\Worker->handle()
#67 [internal function]: {closure}()
#68 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes/vendor/laravel/octane/bin/swoole-server(170): OpenSwoole\Server->start()
#69 {main}
"}

I searched in net and found some refs like :
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/1174
But in this project I do not have any test files and default "tests" subdirectory...
How to run the app with octane serve and if there is a sense to run the app under octane serve to make performance better of the app ?

It is really hard to say what actually has gone wrong because there are so many scenario.But I would suggest you to check if the Octane service provider is correctly registered in config/app.php? Also run this two php artisan config:clear & php artisan cache:clear  before serving the app to see if the issue resolved. If not then let me know.

And regarding this Target class [config] does not exist. error, this is BindingResolutionException.

My config/app.php have no reference to octane and reading docs :
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/octane I did not find if config/app.php must have octane referenced? Please point...
PS. I recreated the app to 11 branch(I mean new app with code moving) and my bootstrap/app.php also have no octane referenced.
